# Retrieve emails to Gmail via POP3 from non-standard Gmail?

Tags: gmail, pop3

I have my primary account through Gmail (`example@gmail.com`) and another email account (`something@somewhere.com`). This second account is part of a Google Apps service on a third-party domain (and therefore is owned by said third party). I want to be able to receive these emails in my primary account. Normally, between two Gmail accounts you would just be able to use "Grant access to your account" option. However, the Google Apps-based account only allows this feature to be used by accounts on the same domain. So I'm attempting to use POP3 with the settings:

```
Email: something@somewhere.com
Username: something (also tried something@somewhere.com)
Password: password
Pop Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 995
```

But this always results in:

```
Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
Server returned error: "[AUTH] Username and password not accepted."
```

I've tried several variations of POP servers and ports and still no success.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Not sure how to do this with POP3 but IMAP is far superior. If they offer IMAP access I personally would use Outlook/Postbox/Thunderbird for this. It is a real shame they don't allow you to use your normal GMail account for this. It defeats the purpose of using Google tools. We want 1 inbox ppl!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail pop settings are as follows:

```
Email: something@somewhere.com
Username: something@somewhere.com
server: pop.googlemail.com
port: 995
```

another thing, you need to login first to `something@somewhere.com` gmail's web interface, and enable pop3 access to it, otherwise you will not be able to access it through pop, you will find it in the settings.

Comment: Still getting the same error. And I do have POP3 enabled on the other account. Any other ideas?

Comment: @golmschenk try to put the server `pop.gmail.com` , if that still didn't work, contact the domain administrator and ask him to enable pop access, check this: https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=105694

Comment: Yeah, I gave `pop.gmail.com` a try already as well. The strange thing is, I've switched my account settings already and the google app email clearly states that POP3 is enabled.

Comment: @golmschenk For me it was 2-factor authentication blocking the POP access. Going to my Google Account settings, and setting up an App password, and using that password in the POP connection worked.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have tried the correct steps. You should check with the administrator of somewhere.com

**Administrators of a Google Apps domain can disable POP and IMAP.**

Relevant Google Support article:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=105694